# Javascript 'this' keyword returning href attribute rather than Object on anchor tag

Tags: javascript, object, onclick

**Requirement**: Return the element object.
**Problem**: Using the code below, I *expected* the links to return [object], but they actually return the string in the href attribute (or in the case of the first link, the Window object).

(The HTML below has been tested in FireFox 3.6.8 and Internet Explorer 7 (7.0.6002.18005) with the same results.)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
      <title>Anchor onclick tests</title>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <a href="javascript:alert(this);" title="">&lt;a href=&quot;javascript:alert(this);&quot;&gt;...&lt;a/&gt;</a> - Returns: [object Window]<br />
            <a href="#" onclick="alert(this);" title="">&lt;a href=&quot;#&quot; onclick=&quot;alert(this);&quot;&gt;...&lt;a/&gt;</a> - Returns: Full URI<br />
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="alert(this);" title="">&lt;a href=&quot;javascript:void(0);&quot; onclick=&quot;alert(this);&quot;&gt;...&lt;a/&gt;</a> - Returns: javascript:void(0);
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Adding `.tagname` to the this keyword returns `undefined` for the first link but correctly identifies the second and third as `A`. Likewise, requesting `.href` returns `undefined` for the first link but correctly outputs the href (full URI in the case of '#').

Does anyone know why, and how I can get a hold on the `A` object itself?

Comment: 'this' refers to the execution context. For the first, 'this' refers to global i.e. window object. And for the latter two 'this' refers to 'a' object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you said, accessing a property in the second and third link works. That means that `this` is indeed the `A` DOM element but when it is converted to a string (which is what happens when you want to `alert` it) it is converted to the URL.

So you already have your object ;)

Same happens when you do `alert(document.location)`. It is actually an object but when converted to a string, it prints the current location.

Comment: Thanks for the answer(s). I've worked with js for years and never realised that. I have learned something new (well, old really, but never mind) today.

Answer (score 1):

When `alert` is invoked, the `toString` method is internally invoked so for the case of the anchors alerting the href, the toString of anchors returns the href instead.

```
<a id="foo" href="blah">fsdjl</a>
```

In the JS console, do:

```
document.getElementById('foo').toString()
```

This would confirm it.

As for `window`, `this` isn't bound to a method owned by the anchor, so `this` refers to the global context. `onclick` is bound to the anchor so `this`, aka current execution context, changes to the anchor.

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:alert( this.nodeName )">blah</a>
```

The result is it alerts `A` which is the nodeName, so the browser does return the `href` if there is an `href` set so it's more "readable" and less vague.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That certainly help explain it.