# "this" in jQuery $(selector).each function refers to page

Tags: javascript, jquery

Under what circumstances does "this" and "element" in the code below refer to the page instead of the selector?

```
$("a.tag")
    .each(
        function (index, element) {
           console.log("'this' is " + this);
           console.log("'element' is " + element);
        }
    )
```

produces the following as many times as there are  elements:

```
'this' is file:///C:/Projects/PlaceTag/PlaceTag/default.html# default.html:50
'element' is file:///C:/Projects/PlaceTag/PlaceTag/default.html#
```

Comment: Interesting... never seen that before: http://jsfiddle.net/nYHfb/

Comment: @JasonP the same phenomenon was mentioned [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363848/javascript-this-keyword-returning-href-attribute-rather-than-object-on-anchor)

Comment: Try console.log(this === el);

Comment: I just love it when debugging code is what breaks the application!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both `this` and `element` always refer to the DOM element in a `.each()` callback.

Your code coerces the DOM element to a string through the `+` concatenation operator.
This returns the element's `href` property.

Instead, you can pass the object itself to `log()`:

```
console.log("'this' is ", this);
```

Comment: Shouldn't string coercion result in `[object Object]` instead of the page URL?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: `HTMLAnchorElement` has its own `toString()`.

Answer (score 0):

Any time you use .each, your context changes and thus 'this' changes.  The easy solution would be to add a reference to 'this'.

```
var self = this;
$("a.tag")
.each(
    function (index, element) {
       console.log("'self' is " + self);
       console.log("'this' is " + this);
       console.log("'element' is " + element);
    }
)
```

Comment: That's the opposite of what he wants.

Comment: It's still a valuable insight. Thank you for your answer.